# Provide a RSS feed with nodeJS/Express and React as a frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, rss

I have an already running website which frontend is made with React and a nodeJS/Express backend.

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to offer an RSS feed, but I don't know how to approach this.

I've found some ways to generate the RSS feed file (XML I suppose) in the backend, but then I'm not sure how to make it available in the frontend since it's a React one, in my server configuration (NGINX) every URL is redirected to the root and React takes care of routing. That's why I don't know how to make the RSS available in the frontend.

Also, I'm not sure what's the URL "convention" for serving RSS feed. I've seen some URLs with the protocol **feed://** or ending in **/rss** too.

In the webpage we have some categories, so we'll have RSS for each of them, not just the root.

Any help on how to approach this problem will be more than welcome.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a way to do what I was looking for. This is what I've done, in case someone faces the same issues and can find this helpful.

I've added a new **location** in my NGINX configuration file:

```
location ~ ^[\/](?<tag>.*)[\/](feed) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/feed/$tag;
}
```

The **regex** in that location is going to match any URL that contains **/feed** at the end of it and it's going to store in the variable **tag** the string of the "category" that I want to send to the backend to render the RSS feed.

So, for example, this will match: `https://mywebpage.com/category/feed` and it will store **category** in the variable tag.

With this done, just need to make the `/feed` endpoint available at the nodeJS/Express backend side.